# QField 1.4.4 Photo Error

Tags: qfield

I'm trying out QField 1.4.4 and get this error when trying to attach photos to point data.
Value **"DCIM/JPEG_20200303_130156.jpg" NOT NULL could not be converted to a compatible value for field Photo_1(String).**
Using a Google Pixel with Android version 10.

Comment: Are there spaces in the file name? Perhaps that makes trouble.

Comment: what data type is the column of your foto-attachment column?

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem, using a Pixel 4 with Android 10. I was following the manual from QGIS: https://livelihoods-and-landscapes.com/qgis_qfield_tutorials/lesson_1.html#Layer_Creation

The solution for me was to increase the number of characters, the manual says 10 but I put 200 and then it worked. My guess is that if the path length is +10 chars it didn't work